# GCP forwarding rules

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ip

The applied static IP is regional, and the forwarding rule also sets the region.

Why does the In-use IP addresses global in the quota increase after forwarding?

When forwarding the 5th rule, the prompt: Quota 'IN_USE_ADDRESSES' exceeded. Limit: 4.0 globally

Comment: @FerreginaPelona - your comment is the answer. Add a link to request a quota increase.

Answer (score 1):

Because you only can have 4 forwarding rules across regions, this is why it is called global, otherwise the quota would per region.

If you are adding Forwarding Rules (which is the technical name of the GCP Load Balancers) with public IPs it is expected.

You may need to ask for a quota increase if you need more using this [link](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?service=compute.googleapis.com&metric=%22Forwarding%20rules%22&_ga=2.58988526.215128258.1647719924-2040157236.1646194394).

You can see more [here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/quotas#forwarding_rules)

Comment: But the 4 IPs and the instance are all in the same area, such as us-central1-a。

Comment: Re-read my answer “Because you only can have 4 forwarding rules across regions”. In other words, the sum of the forwarding rules in all regions should be at most 4 in your case

Comment: I mean both IP and forwarding are in the same area. Why is it called cross-area? The start and end points of forwarding are both us-central1. Shouldn't they belong to the same region?

From us-central1 to europe-north1 should be called cross-region.

Comment: It does not matter if those start-end in the same region or zone, what matters is where those were created.